# How do I write a JS function to disable the function under certain conditions

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a simple game in JS. It's essentially a game of chance. You press a button (which runs a function) and if it doesn't return number 9 then it shows a picture,  you get a point and keep going. If it does return a 9 you see a losing picture and you loose. The game waits two seconds, (so you can actually see the losing image) and then throws an alert message telling you your high score and then refreshes the page.

The problem is between the two seconds of you loosing and receiving the alert message you can still click and receive points. Is there a way to disable the function form being called again? I am looking for a way to do this.

```
var didIGetAPoint = function() {
if(num != losing number) {
   show pic, get a point and keep going
}
else { show losing pic, disable this function from running again, pause, then alert box.}
}
```

Comment: Disable the button that is easier

Comment: You *can* `didIGetAPoint = function(){};`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a boolean variable to set whether the game is over or not.

Here is my example. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hhvx87nq/)

HTML

```
<button id="pointbutton" onclick="clickforpointsandlose()">Click me to earn points and Lose!</button>
```

JS

```
    var points = 0;
var isaLoser = false;

    function clickforpointsandlose(){
     if(!isaLoser) {
       //show pic, get a point and keep going
         points+=1;
         console.log("total points "+ points);
    }
    else {         
        console.log("You can't earn points because you already lost.");
        //show losing pic, disable this function from running again,         pause, then alert box.}
    }

    }

console.log("You are losing in 2 seconds");
 loserhaha = setTimeout(function(){
     alert("You Lose!");
     isaLoser = true;
 }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of doing it would be to disable your button ( remove the onclick handler & set the button disabled attribute).

you can do something like this.

```
var gameover = false;
var didIGetAPoint = function() {
    if(num != losing number) {
       if (gameover === true) {return false;}
       show pic, get a point and keep going
    }
    else { show losing pic, disable this function from running again, pause, then alert box.
        gameover = true;
    }
}
```